# How to change line style of highstock multiple series data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, highcharts

[image: prediction graph]

however what I wanted was something like this:

[image: actual prediction graph design]

The green line is past data until the three line intersects and blue green and black after interaction are the predicted data.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$ ->
  seriesOptions = []
  seriesCounter = 0
  names = [
    'good'
    'bad'
    'average'
  ]
  current_time = new Date();
  # set data 
  window.scenario = $("#portfolio_chart").data('scenario')
  ###
  # Create the chart when all data is loaded
  # @returns {undefined}
  ###

  createChart = ->
    $('#portfolio_chart').highcharts 'StockChart',
      legend:
        enabled: true
        layout: 'horizontal',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y:25
      rangeSelector: selected: 5
      yAxis:
        labels: formatter: ->
          (if @value > 0 then ' + ' else '') + @value + '%'
        plotLines: [ {
          value: 0
          width: 2
          color: 'silver'
        } ]
      plotOptions:
        series:
          compare: 'value'
          turboThreshold: 0
      tooltip:
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>'
        valueDecimals: 2
        formatter: ->
          if this.x > current_time
            good = this.points[0]
            average = this.points[2]
            bad = this.points[1]
            date = '<b><span style="color: black"><b>Date:</b> ' + new Date(good.x) + '</span></b><br>'
            good_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + good.color + '">' + good.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + good.y + '</b> <br>'
            average_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + average.color + '">' + average.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + average.y + '</b> <br>'
            bad_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + bad.color + '">' + bad.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + bad.y + '</b> <br>'
            return date + good_tooltip + average_tooltip + bad_tooltip;
          else
            average = this.points[2]
            date = '<span style="color: black"><b>Date:</b> ' + new Date(average.x) + '</span></b><br>'
            average_tooltip = '<span style="color:' + average.color + '">' + average.series.name + '</span> : <b>' + average.y + '</b> <br>'
            return date + average_tooltip;
      series: seriesOptions
    return

  $.each names, (i, name) ->
    seriesOptions[i] =
      name: name
      data: scenario[name]
      type: 'spline'
    # As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
    # we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
    seriesCounter += 1
    if seriesCounter == names.length
      createChart()
```

This is what my data kind off look likes

```
{
  "good": [
    [
      1401494400000,
      8113.13579312755
    ],
    [
      1404086400000,
      10783.7898823944
    ],
    [
      1406764800000,
      9884.49351907268
    ],
    [
      1409443200000,
      10232.5275921684
    ],
    [
      1412035200000,
      7346.77658737733
    ],
    [
      1414713600000,
      9372.51299197348
    ] ............... ,
  "average": [
    [
      1401494400000,
      8113.13579312755
    ],
    [
      1404086400000,
      10783.7898823944
    ],
    [
      1406764800000,
      9884.49351907268
    ],
    [
      1409443200000,
      10232.5275921684
    ],
    [
      1412035200000,
      7346.77658737733
    ],
    [
      1414713600000,
      9372.51299197348
    ],
    [
      1417305600000,
      9911.7987635224
    ],
    [
      1419984000000,
      9502.02582437336
    ]........,
  "bad": [
    [
      1401494400000,
      8113.13579312755
    ],
    [
      1404086400000,
      10783.7898823944
    ],
    [
      1406764800000,
      9884.49351907268
    ],
    [
      1409443200000,
      10232.5275921684
    ],
    [
      1412035200000,
      7346.77658737733
    ],
    [
      1414713600000,
      9372.51299197348
    ],
    [
      1417305600000,
      9911.7987635224
    ],
    [
      1419984000000,
      9502.02582437336
    ],
    [
      1422662400000,
      8347.10066887184
    ].......
}
```

My Question is How do I get the graph look like the expected graph, apologies for a really absolute question, but I am kinda newbie to this?

How do I made the past data into area distribution graph and future data into line with different line style?

Any type of help on how to tackle this problem will be of much help.
Thank You!

Comment: You'd probably have to make them separate series from the start to the intersection as area, and then another set of separate series from the intersection to the end as line.

Comment: I thank for your reply, I did came across the idea of separating the series,
but didn't knew how to join the two separate series. coz one had only one set of series and other had had three series. so, what I did was made a set of three series from the beginning, where for past data I repeated the series for other two i.e good and bad, hence it overlapped and when the data changed at particular point, it branched out for future data.

But I dnt knw how can I take a single series so I can have a different type of graph line style for past data and join it to multiple series, any suggestions?